# I would like to read an example of ArrayList with Objects.(Java)

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have created two classes and I am trying to invoke a constructor(with argument) and a method. I find it easy if I just use an object.

My Goal :

1. To invoke the same method by using 3 objects.
2. Use ArrayList to invoke the method 3 times.

My Homework:
I did google a bit. I happen to end with explanation of ArrayList and certain examples of it. I did not find examples which I think I need i.e. using ArrayList with Objects(like my citation).

```
public class DrawGraphics
{
    BouncingBox box;

    /** Initializes this class for drawing. */
    public DrawGraphics()
    {

            box = new BouncingBox(200, 50, Color.green);

            box.setMovementVector(1, 1);
    }
//..................
//................
}
```

Thank you for those who try to help.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have an array list at all. What do you mean by "invoke the same method by using 3 objects"? Please show the code you tried to do both, even if it doesn't compile/work so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All Java Collections are designed to contain Objects (and not primitives) so I am quite puzzled by what you say: **all** examples of ArrayList will use objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing with your example this might give you an idea of what Lists can be used for:

```
// Let's create an ArrayList that will contain the bouncingboxes
List<BouncingBox> boxList = new ArrayList<BouncingBox>();    

// Let's create 5 of them and add them to the end of the List
for (int ii=0;ii<5;ii++) {
    boxList.add(new BouncingBox(200, 50, Color.green));
}

// Iterate over the List we just created with the enhanced for - the method will
// be called on all objects in the List.
for (BouncingBox box : boxList) {
    box.setMovementVector(1, 1);
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this wont help the original poster unless they are taking the class over but:

The details of this assignment are available on MIT "opencourseware" the goal of the assignment is to create 3 different objects by modifying provided code, an array list is not needed, an array is not needed for that matter, you simple create additional boxes by adding similar code

ie:

```
box = new BouncingBox(200, 50, Color.green);
box.setMovementVector(1, 1);

box2 = new BouncingBox(100, 100, Color.cyan);
box2.setMovementVector(2,-1);
```

etc...

the second function in that same class needs to be modified as well, it will look something like this:

```
   public void draw(Graphics surface) {
        surface.drawLine(50, 50, 250, 250);
        box.draw(surface);
        box2.draw(surface);
        box3.draw(surface);
    }
```

note that if you're actually interested in programming as a career or hobby, but don't understand what you're doing in class, it's a good idea to ask for help. Simply copying the answers online will not save you in the real world.